# Is it possible to create a WS-client from WSDL file using Spring-WS? (It seems not)

Tags: java, spring, wsdl, spring-ws

**I'd like to know if it's possible to create Web Services client from a WSDL file using Spring Web Services**.

I mean from the very WSDL, I don't have any XSD for the time being.

But I've read Josh Long's "Spring Recipes A Problem-Solution Approach", Hamidreza Sattari's "Spring Web Services 2 Cookbook" and the tutorial itself ([6. Using Spring Web Services on the Client](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/client.html)) and there's no reference to this feature.

I've also read other posts, like [Webservice-Client: Common approach with Spring WS, JAXB and just one WSDL file?](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?112200), or [Spring-ws client from WSDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641046/spring-ws-client-from-wsdl) (here at stackoverflow) but without any further results.

I've even asked the question at Spring forums, but no responses after more than 60 reads: [Is it possible to create a WS-client from WSDL file using SWS? (It seems not)](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?133116)

Maybe it's not possible.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "create a WS-client"? Because you can use the WebServiceTemplate class to wrap anything you want in a SOAP message. I suspect that you're really thinking about creating POJO classes that the client can use. If you have a `type` section in the WSDL, then you can run that WSDL through the XJC compiler and get your classes out.

Comment: ¿No further results? What errors have you found in the process? What have you tried? Show some code, please.

Comment: Thanks @kdgregory, what I really meant is that I want to [Send and receive POJOs: marshalling and unmarshalling](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/client.html#d5e1811), so XJC is what I need.

Thanks to Alfabravo too, for showing interest in my issue. My only problem was to generate the POJOs as kdgregory said. I could [send a WebServiceMessage with WebServiceTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/client.html#d5e1787), but the static String message (for creating a StreamSource using a StringReader) wasn't what I wanted.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do it this way:

1. Generate your java types using the xjc tool that comes with the JDK distributions - `xjc -wsdl file.wsdl`
2. Then using the generated java types, use WebserviceTemplate, described [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/client.html#client-web-service-template) to create the client.

Comment: I didn't know the -wsdl option (actually I'm used to working with maven, so I usually work with some plugin as jaxb2-maven-plugin to call XJC, without further dig into details)

Thanks @Biju Kunjummen for showing me the correct option.

Tomorrow I will try it.

Comment: You can still use the maven plugin to generate classes based on the wsdl, check out [this option](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/xjc-mojo.html#wsdl).

Comment: Out of curiosity- do you know how to generate the xjc -wsdl command from eclipse? I created an eclipse project, right clicked on the wsdl file, and looked at the different options under the "Web Services" menu but none of them seemed right.